# Are there any Java graphic libraries that take in RGB values as inputs?

Tags: java, graphics

I apologize if this is the wrong place to ask - please let me know if it is, and I will remove this post.

My question is - are there any Java graphic libraries that can take RGB values as inputs and maps those onto a graph? I have been looking at JFreeChart, and a number of the open source solutions, but looking at the documentation, I haven't been having much luck.

Currently, I have a multi-dimensional array that stores 1302 RGB values, which corresponds to 93 rows and 14 columns. As each "index" stores a RGB string in this format i.e. `0,0,0` I hope to graph each individual color into a x-y graph such as like this: [image]

In the above graph, the black is a `0,0,0` value, while the cyan, green, red, etc, are all their individual RGB values.

Comment: What do you mean with "take RGB values and map those onto a graph"? RGB is a three coordinate system, a graph is typically 2 dimensional, so: no, I wouldn't expect there to be, since that's impossible. Can you update your post to describe what you intend to end up with, so that we can understand what you're asking help with?

Comment: I apologize for that. I have added more information.

Comment: So is what you're asking how to plot a 2D array of RGB values by plotting the values as color boxes. Except what you're showing looks more like a fairly standard intensity plot, with black being "no value", blue being "low intensity" and red being "high intensity". Do your colors means anything, or are they just colors? Because I strongly suspect we have an XY problem here. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: The colors do mean something - it's temperature.

Comment: This should be doable in Java Swing libraries. I remember waaaay back in 2004 when I had an assignment to draw Mandelbrots pixel by pixel based on intensity. Ah! Here we are. http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/32class/Mandelbrot.java.html See if this sets you in the right direction, then come back and ask a question if you get stuck or this http://java.rubikscube.info/

Comment: @Compass That link appears to be dead =). EDIT: Oops, nevermind. It works now.

Comment: @Compass My IDE does not seem to know what `Complex` and `Picture` is, and `Ctrl+Shift+i` does not appear to add in the additional libraries necessary. Can you tell me what's wrong?

Comment: @theGreenCabbage so ask about that. Is there a Java library for plotting a heatmap? Answer: yes, there are many. http://www.tc33.org/projects/jheatchart/ for instance. Just because your values are encoded as "RGB Strings" doesn't mean you want to ask about using RGB strings, you want to ask about plotting temperature values. The fact that they're RGB strings is irrelevant since we can transform them however we need to make them suitable input.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Thank you! That's precisely what I need. Honestly, I didn't know it would be called heatmap, but now that I think about it, that's exactly what it is.

Comment: @theGreenCabbage you would have to develop those in the first one (it was originally a class assignment where you take the original program, and based on the provided data structure, convert it to Java.) The applet code following would probably be more helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're asking about plotting heat maps, the answer is yes. Many, in fact, but one such library is jHeatChart over at http://tc33.org/projects/jheatchart

Note that just because your values are encoded as "RGB Strings" doesn't mean you want to ask about using RGB strings, you want to ask about plotting temperature values. The fact that they're RGB strings is irrelevant since we can transform them however we need to make them suitable input.